# Use Power Series to solve system of differential equations

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

**Problem:**

Hello, I wonder how you would use a Power Series to solve a system of differential equations.

Lets say I have the system

$$\begin{cases}(1)\text{ }\text{ }x_1'=2x_1+4x_2 \\
(2)\text{ }\text{ }x_2'=3x_1-2x_2.\end{cases}$$

How would you solve such a system using power series? I can't really see it (this particular system came straight out of my head, so I don't know how easy it is to solve using power series).

---

I was thinking to just let $x_1=\sum\limits_{n\geq 0}a_nt_1^n$ and then we would have $x_1'=\sum\limits_{n\geq 1}n\cdot a_nt_1^{n-1}$. I guess I would do the same for $x_2$ to get $x_2=\sum\limits_{n\geq 0}b_nt_2^n$ and $x_2'=\sum\limits_{n\geq 1}n\cdot b_nt_2^{n-1}$ and then substitute this into the system to get

$$$$\begin{cases}(1)\text{ }\text{ }\sum\limits_{n\geq 1}n\cdot a_nt_1^{n-1}=2\sum\limits_{n\geq 0}a_nt_1^n+4\sum\limits_{n\geq 0}b_nt_2^n \\
(2)\text{ }\text{ }\sum\limits_{n\geq 1}n\cdot b_nt_2^{n-1}=3\sum\limits_{n\geq 0}a_nt_1^n-2\sum\limits_{n\geq 0}b_nt_2^n.\end{cases}$$$$

---

**Questions:**

I don't really know where to go from here. I don't really know how I should treat a differential equation with two different power-series in it. So my thoughts were to try to eliminate $t_1$ (or $t_2$) from one of the equations and then solve that equations just as I would normally do and then substitute(?) that solution back to the other equation.

If this is correct, how do I do the elimination part? Should I first try to match the indexes with each other and then do the elimination?

---

**Continue of problem:**

I would, in this case, have

$$$$\begin{cases}\sum\limits_{n\geq 0}(n+1)\cdot a_{n+1}t_1^{n}=2\sum\limits_{n\geq 0}a_nt_1^n+4\sum\limits_{n\geq 0}b_nt_2^n \\
\sum\limits_{n\geq 0}(n+1)\cdot b_{n+1}t_2^{n}=3\sum\limits_{n\geq 0}a_nt_1^n-2\sum\limits_{n\geq 0}b_nt_2^n.\end{cases}$$$$

That is,

$$$$\begin{cases}\sum\limits_{n\geq 0}((n+1)a_{n+1}t_1^{n}-2a_n)t_1^n=4\sum\limits_{n\geq 0}b_nt_2^n \\
3\sum\limits_{n\geq 0}a_nt_1^n=\sum\limits_{n\geq 0}((n+1)\cdot b_{n+1}+2b_n)t_2^{n}.\end{cases}$$$$

AND NOW, I seriously don't know how to do the elimination. I want to subtract a multiple of (1) from (2) for example to get rid of one of the series. But I guess this wasn't any good idea. I also thought about trying to get it "back" into a second degree differential equation, but it wasn't that easy as I first thought.

---

**Last Questions:**

Why would I even solve a system of differential equations using power series, in this case I could just find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors and then I'm done. Can you solve a System like

$$X'=AX+B$$ using power series? Then I can understand why the professor mentioned that power series can be good to know for the exam when you want to solve a system of diff. equations.

I am pretty lost right now and would love to get some help. At least get the layout, the method, how to use powerseries to solve system of differential equations. Thanks :)

**Edit:**

Now I am really not sure, should $x_1$ and $x_2$ depend on the same variable $t$ or two different, say $t_1$ and $t_2$?

Comment: You might want to try: http://www.ijirset.com/upload/2014/april/106_MR.yekta.pdf . You might also want to try Picard Iteration.

Comment: Oh thank you very much Moo, I will try  ijirset.com/upload/2014/april/106_MR.yekta.pdf. It looks good :)

Comment: In general, I would say that you "do not" want to use series or Picard on systems of equations as there is the much better approach that you noted.

Comment: I'm assuming both $x_1$ and $x_2$ are functions of the same variable  $t $. Then both power series should be in $t$ as well, i.e. $t_1=t_2=t $.

Comment: @Joel In my book, to mention to somebody that they have a more serious trouble understanding a subject than simply mistyping, is giving them a service since this is the only way they can realize the situation and try to remedy it. That you fail to understand this simple point is your problem. But that you try to slander me on the site is not acceptable. Hence: comment flagged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From (1) we have $x_2 = \frac14 x_1' - \frac12 x_1$, and differentiating yields \begin{align}
x_1'' &= 2x_1' + 4x_2'\\
&= 2x_1'+4(3x_1-2x_2)\\
&= 2x_1' + 12x_1 - 2x_1'+4x_1,\\
\end{align}
so we may instead consider the second-order ODE
$$x_1''-16x_1=0. \tag 3$$
Suppose $$x_1(t) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n t^n.$$ Then differentiating and substituting into (3) yields
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n+1)(n+2)a_{n+2}t^n - \sum_{n=0}^\infty 16a_nt^n=0, $$
so that $(n+1)(n+2)a_{n+2}=16a_n$, or $a_{n+2}=\frac{16}{(n+1)(n+2)}a_n$. It follows by induction that
\begin{align}
a_{2(n+1)} &= \frac{16^{n+1}}{(2(n+1))!}a_0\\
a_{2n+3} &= \frac{16^{n+1}}{(2n+3)!}a_1
\end{align} for $n\geqslant 0$, and as $a_0=x_1(0)$, $a_1=x_1'(0)$, we have $$a_n = \frac{x_1(0)4^n+x_1'(0)(-4)^n}{n!}, $$ so that $$x_1(t)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x_1(0)4^n+x_1'(0)(-4)^n}{n!}t^n=x_1(0)e^{4t}+x_1'(0)e^{-4t}. $$
It follows that 
\begin{align}
x_2(t) &= \frac14\frac{\mathsf d}{\mathsf dt}\left[x_1(0)e^{4t}+x_1'(0)e^{-4t}\right]-\frac12\left(x_1(0)e^{4t}+x_1'(0)e^{-4t}\right)\\
&=\left(1-\frac12 x_1(0)\right)e^{4t}-\left(1+\frac12 x_1'(0)\right)e^{-4t}.
\end{align}